# subtract integer from a string of integers

Tags: java, arrays, string

Suppose I have a string array as follows:

```
   String[] str = {"2","4","5"};
```

Now I want to subtract 1 from each of its elements, ie, I want the string to be like this now:

```
    str = {"1","3","4"};
```

How do I do it? Is there any way other than converting it into an integer array?

Comment: You cannot avoid to convert step.

Comment: This is not difficult. [Try something. Put forth some effort.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: If you need to perform mathematical operations on them, perhaps you should consider whether storing them as Strings is really best. Perhaps storing them as `int` so you can operate on them is better, only parsing into `String` when you actually need to?

Comment: Is the range of possible values for the stringed integers limited, or is it potentially infinite ? If the range of possible values isn't too big, and if you have to frequently repeat the same transformation, you could create a dictionnary maping each stringed integer with the string integer below, and then use this dic to do the transformation directly on the elements of the list.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you want to achieve? May be there are some other ways around your problem. Where do get those numbers and what are you going to do with them will help clarify the question.

Comment: @Jack u were right, I used a roundabout method but it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert them into *integers*, but not necessarily store into an *array of integers*. You can do the math *in-place* instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  str[i] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str[i]) - 1);
}
```

However, this is a code smell to me. Strings do not tend to be the best choice when doing math in general. You might also want to work with an `int[]` internally and convert them to strings when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String str[]= {"2","4","5"};
for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
str[i]=String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(str[i])-1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert them to Integers.

If you could make some crazy constraints, you could get it a little better, for example...
Only having single digit integers in an array of characters, strictly greater than zero.  You could then do the "math" by subtracting 1 from their ASCII value, but this is a pretty crazy situation to even ever have.

Comment: But there is no other way??

Comment: Unfortunately, no there isn't really.  This will be an O(n) operation no matter how you spin it, and in order for the math to work out, you need the program to treat them as numbers, since you could be lowering from 100 to 99, which removes a digit, or you could be going from 0 to -1, which "adds" to the zero, but also "adds" the negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

1. convert string to int : `int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");`
2. Subtract 1 from it
3. Convert back to string  `Integer.toString(i)`

That makes

```
for (int i = 0; i < strn.length; i++)
    strn[i] := String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(strn[i]) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    str[i] := String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(str[i]) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you.

```
public String[] stringCal(String[] ele,int numbr){
    String[] sCalulated = new String[ele.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ele.length ; i ++){
        sCalulated[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(ele[i])-numbr);
    }
    return sCalulated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String str[] = subtractOn(new String[]{"2","4","5"});

    for(int k=0;k<str.length;k++){
        System.out.println("Integer is :" +str[k]);
    }

  }

public static String[] subtractOn(String str[]){

    int intArray[] = new int[str.length];
    String stres[] = new String[str.length];

    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<intArray.length;j++){
        stres[j] = String.valueOf(intArray[j]-1);
    }

    return stres;
}
```

Comment: this is being dynamic and will run for every case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.apache.commons.lang3.math` library to solve it in an elegant way.

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  str[i] = NumberUtils.toInt(str[i]) - 1;
}
```